# How to clear form element values after validation error

Tags: 8, forms

I have a rather complex form validation depending on multiple fields. If validation fails, I would like to set the form values (of all or some explicit fields) to an empty value. This is what I tried, but none of the three approaches works:

```
public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  ...
  if (!$authorized) {

    $this->messenger->addError($this->t('An error occured.'));

    $form['name']['#value']=''; // approach 1

    $form_state->setValue('name',''); // approach 2

    $form_state->setValueForElement($form['name'], ''); // approach 3

    $form_state->setRebuild();
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at `unsetValue()`?

Example usage:

```
public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  ...
  if (!$authorized) {

    $this->messenger->addError($this->t('An error occurred.'));

    $form_state->unsetValue('name');

   }
 }
```

From the doc:

> Removes a specific key from the submitted form values.
>
> - @param string|array $key
> - Values are stored as a multi-dimensional associative array. If $key is a string, it will use unset($values[$key]). If $key is an array, each element of the array will be used as a nested key. If $key = array('foo', 'bar') it will use unset($values['foo']['bar']).

Comment: doesn't work, value is still displayed in the form field.

Comment: it seems that $form_state->setUserInput([]); does the trick. But I don't know how to use it to only empty certain form fields. When I use it like this the whole form gets empty.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you were trying to do. It takes an associative array of values: $form_state->setUserInput(['name' => '']);

Comment: I tried like this, but still it empties all values, not only name.

Comment: setUserInput() replaces all existing values. You need to get the user input with getUserInput(), unset the keys you want to have removed, then set it again.

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick for all the form fields:

```
 $form_state->setUserInput([]);
```

I think it should not be used for field validations but for error handling for example.

```
try {
  $res = $this->client->request('GET', '/demandes/' . $demandeId, [
    'headers' => ['Accept' => 'application/json'],
  ]);
  $demandeObject = Json::decode($res->getBody());
}
catch (ConnectException $e) {
  \Drupal::messenger()->addError(t("Une erreur est survenue: Le document n'a pas été ajouté. Veuillez contacter l'administrateur du site si le problème persiste."));
  // Rebuild form
  $form_state->setRebuild();
  // Reset all form fields
  $form_state->setUserInput([]);
}
```